# How to pass metadata using grpc_cli?

Tags: shell, command-line, command-line-interface, command-line-arguments, grpc

How do I use [`grpc_cli`](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/command_line_tool.md) to pass metadata? My expectation is that my server interceptor will be able to consume the `X-FOO` header.

```sh
$ grpc_cli call  --json_input --json_output localhost:7001 \
   hello.HelloWorldService.SayHello "{'name': 'foo'}" \
   -metadata "X-FOO:BAR;";
connecting to localhost:7001
Sending client initial metadata:
X-FOO : BAR;
E0726 13:26:20.231276000 4583892416 call.cc:900]                       validate_metadata: {"created":"@1564172780.231266000","description":"Illegal header key","file":"src/core/lib/surface/validate_metadata.cc","file_line":43,"offset":0,"raw_bytes":"58 2d 46 4f 4f 'X-FOO'"}
E0726 13:26:20.231808000 4583892416 call_op_set.h:942]                 assertion failed: GRPC_CALL_OK == g_core_codegen_interface->grpc_call_start_batch( call_.call(), ops, nops, core_cq_tag(), nullptr)
```

The `-helpfull` documentation says:

```
-metadata (Metadata to send to server, in the form of key1:val1:key2:val2)
  type: string default: ""
```

Environment info:

```
$ brew info grpc;
grpc: stable 1.21.4 (bottled), HEAD
Next generation open source RPC library and framework
https://grpc.io/
/usr/local/Cellar/grpc/1.21.4 (298 files, 24.5MB) *
  Poured from bottle on 2019-06-27 at 08:29:38
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/grpc.rb
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Turns out the metadata key simply needed to be lowercase; e.g. `x-foo`.